# how to select child in one to many relation in jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I want to select parent with child that i want.

But when I select my parent I have to show all the childs

How can i do that?

Example:

```
public class parent{
    private Integer id;
    @OnetoMany
    @JoinColumn(name="parentId")
    private List<child> children;
}

public class child{
    private Integer id;
    private Integer parentId;
}

findByIdAndchildType(Integer id, String type)
```

I want to see : parent(id) - > child (type)

But i can see parent(id) - > child(othertype), child(othertype1), child(type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me that you're trying to get a bi-directional relation. This is possible by adding the mapping to both sides of the relation.

For example, add a `@ManyToOne` mapping to the `Child` entity. Be aware that you should probably remove your `parentId` field since now you can access it by using `child.getParent().getId()`.

```java
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    private Parent parent;
    // Remove parentId field

    // Getters + Setters ...
}
```

> **NOTE**: If you want to keep the `parentId` field, you'll have to choose which two of the mappings (`getParentId()` or `getParent().getId()`) you want to use for inserting and updating entities. The other field should have both `insertable = false` and `updatable = false`.

The next step is to change the `@OneToMany` mapping to use `mappedBy`:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent") // Change this
    private List<Child> children;

    // Getters + Setters ...
}
```

If you want to retrieve a specific child with its parent, you can now create a repository for `Child` entities:

```
public interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Integer> {

}
```

After that, you can get a specific child by using:

```
Optional<Child> child = repository.findById(123); // 123 is the ID of the child in this case
Optional<Parent> parent = child.map(Child::getParent);
```

With Spring boot 1.x that would be:

```
Child child = repository.findOne(123);
Parent parent = null;
if (child != null) {
    parent = child.getParent();
}
```

Comment: Quite an old post but is there any way I can skip the child lookup and directly find parent based on child keys(for example not just PK of child, but other values as well)

Comment: @ParthManaktala Sure, you could write a custom query within the repository. For example `select c.parent from Child c where c.name = ?1` would retrieve the parent of a child which name matches a parameter.

Comment: Ya currently doing that only, just was curious if there was a way to do that using jpa/hibernate itself. Thanks anyways though!!

Comment: @ParthManaktala Can you explain what you mean by using JPA/Hibernate itself? These queries are written in JPQL, which stands for JPA Query Language (and thus, it's part of JPA/Hibernate).